# Local text file to variable in PHP

Tags: php, file, text, upload, local

I'm trying to capture the text in a local .txt file to a PHP variable so I can save to database. I've been at it for hours and no luck. I've tried just about everything but this is what I currently have. Most of it is commented out for debugging.

As-is it just shows me a blank page and doesn't echo anything. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Complete updated code. With errors on I'm getting a notice about an undefined index on line 12.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','1');
?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>upload file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // name of the file

     //$max_filesize = 100000; // Maximum filesize in BYTES
     //$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.
     //  if($ext = "txt") //check for .txt
     //  die('Only .txt files allowed.');
     //  if($size > $max_filesize) //check file size
     //  die('File is too large');

    if(file_exists($filename)){

    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    $str = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
     echo $str;
    fclose($fp); 
     }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And the upload form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Comment: add to the top of the page: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1'); is the form using "userfile" or "file" as a name?

Comment: Can you just confirm whether you want to access files on local filesystem or you want to access files uploaded via a form?

Comment: Is this a file that was uploaded via an HTTP post request? If not, then $_FILES will not help you.

Comment: so many great answers, i'm bout to get my learn on. i'm uploading temporarily, not saving to the serve permanently.

Comment: I have followed all instructions given and I am now getting this notice: Notice: Undefined index: file in /home/a3752680/public_html/uploader.php on line 12

Comment: @higgs Since you're uploading temporarily, then it looks like bth and  ContextSwitch have your answer.

Comment: @TecBrat thanks for the suggestion. I'll do some googling on that now. in the mean time any more suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @HiggsBoson, please update your question with the HTML code for the upload input field.

Comment: @bth done. I'm still getting the error for undefined index. That's the line that defines `$size`. I changed the hidden max size field to 100000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test for `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']` - this is the location of temporary file created on the server. `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` contains the original name of the uploaded file on client's side.

Update the code:

```
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

to

```
$size = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
$filename = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
```

Documentation for the `$_FILES` variable can be found [in PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Check out this [tutorial for uploading files with PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

Apart from that, correct the `$size($filename)` to `filesize($filename)`.

Comment: You'll still have problems with $size($filename) i think

Comment: @bth I tried this and it's still not working. I've posted the updated code in an edit.

Comment: Great! it works! Thanks. Mind telling me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: The index in `$_FILES` array needs to reference the name of your upload field - in your case `uploadedfile`.

Answer (score 0):

use filesize insead of $size so that it reads `$str = fread($fp, filesize($filename));`

Comment: The function in php to do this is called filesize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)